# Constructing Multiplication Table for Multiplication Modulo

Tags: group-theory

I have this question

Consider G={1,5,7,11,13,17} under Multiplication Modulo 18.Construct Multiplication Table for G.I have constructed the following

[image]

Im i correct ?

Comment: The table seems to be correct. You did p.ex. $11\times 17=187$ Then you divided  187 by 18 and the remainder was $7$. I did not check all the boxes though.

Comment: @zoli Yeah, i did the same x18-Multiplication modulo 18- (a*b)mod 18

Comment: There should not be two the same in a given column, yet you have two copies of 5 in the column under the 5. (That column is also missing an 11, and each number should appear in each row/column somewhere.)

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks,but i really did not get what you have meant.Can you point out where i have gone wrong?

Comment: @coffeemath means that 13x5=65 and 65/18 = 3 and the remainder is 11. So In the box (13,5) the 5 is wrong the correct result is 11.

Comment: @zoli Okay .. i hope correcting that single entry will make the table correct.

Comment: I hope so, but you have to check all the $36$ entries. (I've checket $5$-$6$ of them and did not notice the error that @coffeemath found.)

Comment: @zoli okay.... :)

Comment: One good rule of thumb to self-check is that if your group is commutative the multiplication table should be symmetric. As in a symmetric matrix.

Comment: @mathreadler thanks i will note that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When just multiplying in the reals I get:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc} \times & 1 & 5 & 7 & 11 & 13 & 17\\ \hline1 & 1 & 5 & 7 & 11 & 13 & 17\\ 5 & 5 & 25 & 35 & 55 & 65 & 85\\ 7 & 7 & 35 & 49 & 77 & 91 & 119\\ 11 & 11 & 55 & 77 & 121 & 143 & 187\\ 13 & 13 & 65 & 91 & 143 & 169 & 221\\ 17 & 17 & 85 & 119 & 187 & 221 & 289 \end{array}
$$

Then $\mod 18$ we get

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc} \times & 1 & 5 & 7 & 11 & 13 & 17\\ \hline 1 & 1 & 5 & 7 & 11 & 13 & 17\\ 5 & 5 & 7 & 17 & 1 & 11 & 13\\ 7 & 7 & 17 & 13 & 5 & 1 & 11\\ 11 & 11 & 1 & 5 & 13 & 17 & 7\\ 13 & 13 & 11 & 1 & 17 & 7 & 5\\ 17 & 17 & 13 & 11 & 7 & 5 & 1 \end{array}$$

So only the $5$ on the bottom left is wrong, this should be $11$. As it is a commutative group, you should have a symmetry relative to the diagonal, this would provide a quick way that finds this error.

Comment: Thanks.. so for Abelian Groups the diagonal elements will have symmetry,right?

Comment: I mean a symmetry relative to the diagonal: $13 \times 5 = 11 = 5 \times 11$ in your example here.

Comment: Okay..To be clear if i have 17 in the top right part of the diagonal i will have a 17 in the bottom left part and so on.. right?

Comment: Exactly, because the group is abelian e.g. $7\times 5$ must be the same as $5 \times 7$ when looking it up in the table, so the top right triangle is just mirrored along the main diagonal to the bottom left triangle.

Answer (score 2):

Calculating these things are really neat to do in for instance Matlab / Octave.

Two lines:

> ps = [1,5,7,11,13,17];
>
> table = mod(ps'*ps,18)

First line defines the numbers as a row-vector.

Second line does outer product the vector with itself followed by an element-wise modulo.

My output is $$\text{table} = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
1&5&7&11&13&17\\
5&7&17&1&11&13\\
7&17&13&5&1&11\\
11&1&5&13&17&7\\
13&11&1&17&7&5\\
17&13&11&7&5&1
\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: Thanks for the input on matlab.